# Ambiguity in basic arithmetic operations Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, arithmetic-expressions

Here is the scenario:

```
In [5]: (2.0 - 5.0**(0.5)) ** (1.0/3.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d064023f1ac5> in <module>()
----> 1 (2.0 - 5.0**(0.5)) ** (1.0/3.0)

ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power

In [7]: -1.0 ** (1.0/3.0)
Out[7]: -1.0
```

The above operation is being done on a python interpreter. For the first expression, it is giving value error and says that `negative number can't have fractional power` !! So, firstly, why is this error as obviously, -ve numbers can have cube root or fifth root etc. Also, if that is the case, it should be consistent while in second case, it gives no error when -1 is raised to fractional power (1/3).

Can someone explain why is this the case?

Comment: You are using Python 2 arent you?) In py3k that actually works resulting (0.30901699437494756+0.535233134659635j)

Comment: yes, its python2

Comment: Then just complex((2.0 - 5.0**(0.5))) ** (1.0/3.0)

Comment: And I guess cube root of the -ve number should be a -ve real number. @helloworld, So probably there is something wrong in this result as well.

Comment: No, the cube root of a negative number can very well be complex. There are three possible values (whereof two can be complex) that raised to the third power will generate a negative number. And there seems to be no agreement on which to return if you raise a negative number to its 1/3th power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `**` operator has specific binding behaviour; from the [*power operator*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) documentation:

> The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right.
>
> [...]
>
> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): `-1**2` results in `-1`.

So your *second* example is executed as:

```
-(1.0 ** (1.0/3.0))
```

That is to say, the `-` unary operator applies to the result of `**` as that operator binds more tightly. As a result you have positive number is raised to the power 1/3rd, and only then made negative.

In your *first* example, the expression is parsed as

```
(2.0 - (5.0**(0.5))) ** (1.0/3.0)
```

There is no unary operator here, but the `**` power operator does have a higher precedence than the binary `-` subtraction operator.

This then resolves as

```
(2.0 - 2.23606797749979) ** (1.0/3.0)
```

which is

```
(-0.2360679774997898) ** (1.0/3.0)
```

so is trying to raise a negative number to a fraction.

Python 2 `**` (and the `pow()` function) don't support producing a complex number support when the inputs are at most `float` objects. Convert your negative float value to a `complex()` number first:

```
>>> (-1.0) ** 0.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
>>> (-1+0j) ** 0.5
(6.123233995736766e-17+1j)
>>> (2+0j - 5.0**(0.5)) ** (1.0/3.0)
(0.30901699437494756+0.535233134659635j)
```

This changed in Python 3, where a complex result is returned for a negative number raised to a fractional power.

Comment: But still, why is cube root to -ve number is a complex number?

Comment: @vish4071: if you want a complex number output, put complex numbers *in*. Python arithmetic operators on numbers will first be converted to a common type, and the outcome of the operation will be of that common type. If you mix `int` and `float`, everything is converted to `float` first, and the output is `float`. Without a complex number in the equation, you still get `float` output.

Comment: @vish4071: note that his changed in Python 3, you could upgrade and run your expression without issues there.